# Передать интерфейс через конструктор

Tags: c#, интерфейс, dependency-injection

Есть некий интерфейс `IEngine`, который реализован в классах `DieselEngine` и `GasolineEngine`, как сделать так, чтобы этой реализацией смог воспользоваться класс `Car`? Я так понимаю, это надо сделать через конструктор? Конструктор должен принимать ссылку на интерфейс или на класс,который реализовал этот интерфейс?
Сделал через свойство. В методе Main прописал следующее

```
Car car = new Car(_engine:new GasolineEngine());
car.engine.Speak();
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Достаточно сделать свойство `public IEngine engine{get;set;}` и устанавливать его, например, в конструкторе или после него. `public Car(IEngine _engine) {engine = _engine;} `

Comment: Как угодно. Через свойство, через конструктор, ссылку на интерфейс, ссылку на конкретный класс, как угодно.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В вашем случае `IEngine` является зависимостью для `Car`. Основные способы передачи (или *внедрения*) зависимости следующие:

- Через конструктор. Используется в случаях, когда зависимости является обязательной и не используется реализация по умолчанию.

  ```
  private readonly IEngine _engine;

  public Car(IEngine engine)
  {
      _engine = engine;
  }
  ```
- Через свойство. Используется в случаях, когда используется реализация по умолчанию. Например, все машины поставляются с бензиновыми двигателями, но в некоторых могут стоять дизельные:

  ```
  public IEngine Engine { get; set; };

  public Car()
  {
      Engine = new GasolineEngine();
  }

  ...

  var car = new Car()
  {
      Engine = new DieselEngine()
  };
  ```
- Через параметры метода. Используется в случае когда зависимость нужна только очень ограниченному числу методов в классе.

В вашем случае, я думаю, следует использовать внедрение зависимости через конструктор.

При этом зависимости как правило передаются через интерфейс -- особенно если есть несколько реализаций. Согласно принципу внедрения зависимостей, детали должны зависеть от абстракций. Т.е. машина должна зависеть от общих приницпов функционирования двигателя, а не от подробностей того, как он функционирует.

Comment: у Вас `readonly IEngine _engine;` а Вы его меняете `_engine = engine;` не будет ли это исключением?

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик [нет](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/acdd6hb7.aspx).

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик, в конструкторе можно